# Spotting a key combination pressed in Unity3D in GUI.TextArea

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

How can I track that the user pressed `Crtl`+`Enter` in a `GUI.TextArea` ? I have found a way to know that a single key is pressed, using `Event.current`, but that obviously won't work for a key combination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Using events:

```
if (Event.current.control && Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.Return)
    Debug.Log("Ctrl+Enter is pressed!");
```

This condition checks if Ctrl+Enter combination is pressed now (i.e. on current frame).
This check will return true on each frame when Ctrl+Enter is pressed (i.e. continuously).

## Option 2

Using [Input](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html):

```
    bool controlIsPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && controlIsPressed)
        Debug.Log("Ctrl+Enter was pressed");
```

This condition will only be met on frame where actual key press occurred (i.e. once per Enter keystroke).

## Keep in mind

Keep these in mind that `OnGUI` can be (and will be in case of keyboard input) called multiple times a frame. Check `Event.current.type` to get the reason of why OnGUI is called.